# Regular expression in URL

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression, but I constantly get errors.
The `url` is `http://safelease.be/any-word-here/name/`

So this is my regex: `http:\/\/safelease.be\/([A-Z])\/name/`

And these are the errors:

```
http: matches the characters http: literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
safelease matches the characters safelease literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
be matches the characters be literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: These are not errors, these are your pattern explanations. Instead of `([A-Z])`, you most probably want to use `([^\/]+)` and escape the dot.

Comment: But when I test it on: https://regex101.com/ I get no matches

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Ahm0Fz/2

Comment: `http:\/\/safelease.be\/[A-Za-z]+?\/name\/` Will allow letters in either case. It will also make sure that the word is at least one letter long

Answer (score 1):

This expression might likely extract your desired data before the `name`:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?safelease\.be\/(.*?)\/name\/
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bEYwA1/1/)

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bEYwA1/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
http:\/\/safelease\.be\/([^\/]+)\/name\/
                  ^^     ^^^^^^
```

NOTE:

The `\.` pattern matches a literal dot, not just any char. `[^\/]+` will match 1 or more chars other than `/`. So, it will match anything from `be/` and `/name/` but only a single subpart.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ahm0Fz/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fsafelease%5C.be%5C%2F(%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B)%5C%2Fname%5C%2F):

[image]